# Replace switch instruction in that code

Tags: java

I wanted to find how many times 1 number appears in provided another number. I've found a solution for finding 2-digit numbers in another number, but what I wanted to do is to find 1-digit, 2-digit, ..., n-digit numbers in provided number. I dont want to create another case in switch instruction, so my question how can I avoid doing switch to make it work. Code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Provide number:");
    int number1 = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Provide number you want to find in number1:");
    int number2 = sc.nextInt();

    int counter = 0;
    int digit = 1;
    int a = 10;

    while(number2/a>0){
        digit++;
        a = a*10;
    }

    switch(digit){
        case 1:{
            while(number1 > 0 ){
                if(number1 % 10 == number2){
                    counter++;
                }
                number1 = number1/10;
            }
        }
        case 2:{
            while(number1 > 0){
                if(number1 % 100 == number2){
                    counter++;
                }
                number1 = number1/10;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you already got your answer. Just use your variable a.

```
while(number1 > 0){
   if(number1 % a == number2){
        counter++;
   }
   number1 = number1/10;
}
```

Comment: Should I add this instruction to case or add it instead of case?

Comment: Get rid of the case instruction and replace it with this. Should work just fine. You can change the expression in my instruction with Mr. Eggen's expression (number1 >= number2), it'll work a lot better when number2 has more digits than 1.

Answer (score 0):

As this reeks of home work, just some ideas.

```
int entireNumber = 12345;
int soughtPartNumber = 234;

// Find the power of 10 that caps the soughtPartNumber (1000):
int cap = 1;
while (soughtPartNumber * 10 < cap) {
    cap *= 10;
}

// Search in the number as you did:
while (entireNumber >= soughtPartNumber) {
    ... (entireNumber % cap) == ...
    entireNumer /= 10; // Remove the right digit
}
```

Comment: I dont understand second while loop. To be more specific what is "... (entireNumber % cap) == ..." doing?

Comment: I did not write all. One would do 12345 % 1000 == 345; 1234 % 1000 == 234, 123